# How to check the url of previous page on pageload in C#

Tags: c#

I have three pages in my website.(Home Page,Cart Page,Checkout Page)
On both Cart and Checkout page i have button named Continue Shopping.
IF the user clicks on continue shopping button on any of the page(Cart and Checkout) than i dont want to delete the cart table data(which contains product name,price,total).
I am deleting cart table data on the page load event of home page by checking two values which i have passed as querystring when redirecting continue shopping on both the pages.
I am requesting the querystring values on home page load event and if i found the values than am not deleting the data.
The problem is home page is the default start page of website.
When i start my application the home page load event is fired and it is not able to find the querystring values and so it deletes the cart table data everytime the home page is loaded

Comment: Not answering your question, but I think you need to rethink the cart deletion process. It doesn't sound right if the default behaviour of the page is to delete, and you have to check for something to make sure the deletion doesn't happen. Maybe by default the page should not delete, and if there is ?delete=1 that's when the deletion happens.

Answer (score 2):

`Request.UrlReferrer` can give you UrL of the previous request

```
Uri previousUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have tried it.But the the first page of  the website is home page and when it loades  previousUrl has null.So there is an exception.Tried catching the exception but when i click continue shopping button ,still previousurl gets null